# Can I configure Siteminder with WIF

Tags: identity, saml-2.0, siteminder

I am using the Identity and access tool to configure my service to use siteminder authentication. When I choose the metadata STS provided by siteminder, i get error ID0011, there is not metadata document.

Is the STS not proper or is it not possible to configure this to work with siteminder.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it, check the answer to following question :

[Error "WIF10201: No valid key mapping found" when trying to create claims from SAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014101/error-wif10201-no-valid-key-mapping-found-when-trying-to-create-claims-from-s)

Regards