# Error "WIF10201: No valid key mapping found" when trying to create claims from SAML

Tags: x509certificate, wif, saml-2.0, siteminder, adfs2.1

I am trying to validate a SAML response which is coming from Siteminder IDP from a third party. I have installed the certificate provided by them. When I call the **ValidateToken** method (System.IdentityModel.Tokens) to create claims, I get following error :

> WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for 
>   securityToken:'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' and
>   issuer: 'issuer uri'

I dug in deep to find the error and its being thrown by method **GetIssuerName** (System.IdentityModel.Tokens).

Where is the problem? I googled for this issue but didn't find anything specific to my case. Does the SAML token from my client have a problem or there is something I am missing in implementation. I am fairly new to federated auth so please excuse any inaccuracy with the terminology used.

Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution but could't quite understand the readon behind it (complete noob, will update the answer when I know more).

Followed this approach of converting the SAML2 response to WSFed response, then on that new token I ran my code, now the error is gone.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bradleycotier/archive/2012/10/28/saml-2-0-tokens-and-wif-bridging-the-divide.aspx

Note : you still have to override the validate token method (which I had originally done) to avoid the following error :

```
“ID4154: A Saml2SecurityToken cannot be created from the Saml2Assertion because it contains a SubjectConfirmationData which specifies an InResponseTo value. Enforcement of this value is not supported by default. To customize SubjectConfirmationData processing, extend Saml2SecurityTokenHandler and override ValidateConfirmationData.”
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some could face this issue due  to the ending forward slash in the Issuer url. Remove it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a configuration that maps the issuer name (as specified inside the token) to the certificate (probably specified with a thumbprint).  I guess you solve this with  some configuration in your web.config.  Have a look at p.e. [Microsoft validating issuer name registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.validatingissuernameregistry(v=vs.115).aspx) The page contains some sample configuration.  Setting this up correctly depends entirely on your situation.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and post my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a note for future reference, since I also ran into this error but my resolution was different. I got the WIF10201 error in a custom MVC application that is using ADFS (3.0) claims-based authentication under Windows Server 2012. In the `web.config` of the MVC application, the thumbprint of the ADFS token signing key is recorded. It turns out, when the signing certificate is about to expire, ADFS creates a new key. The new key is marked "primary" and the old key is marked as "secondary" in the ADFS console (under AD FS/Service/Certificates). So in my `web.config` there was, of course, still the thumbprint of the old (secondary) key. As soon as I replaced it with the thumbprint of the new (primary) key, the error disappeared.